# When column A values match, replace column B NAs with column B value

Tags: r, merge, pattern-matching, na

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on two variables (Entrez.ID and Gene.ID). One data frame has only those variables e.g.

```
Entrez.ID  Gene.ID
10007      GNPDA1
10016      ALG2
10044      SH2D3C
```

and one data frame which has three variables, e.g.

```
Entrez.ID    Gene.ID   Ensembl.ID
10007        GPI       ENSG00000113552
10016        PDCD6     ENSG00000249915
10044        CHAT      ENSG00000095370
```

Currently when I merge files using:

```
df<-merge(df1,df2,by=c("Entrez.ID","Gene.ID"),all=TRUE)
```

I get a data frame which looks like:

```
Entrez.ID   Gene.ID   Ensembl.ID
10007       GNPDA1    <NA>
10007       GPI       ENSG00000113552
10016       ALG2      <NA>
10016       PDCD6     ENSG00000249915
10044       SH2D3C    <NA>
10044       CHAT      ENSG00000095370
```

but what I want to create is a data frame which looks like:

```
Entrez.ID   Gene.ID   Ensembl.ID
10007       GNPDA1    ENSG00000113552
10007       GPI       ENSG00000113552
10016       ALG2      ENSG00000249915
10016       PDCD6     ENSG00000249915
10044       SH2D3C    ENSG00000095370
10044       CHAT      ENSG00000095370
```

How do I tell R that where the Entrez.ID variable match, I want the Ensembl.ID to match (i.e. to replace NA with the Ensembl.ID where available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df$Ensembl.ID <- with(df, ave(Ensembl.ID, Entrez.ID, FUN = function(x)
        na.locf(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE)))
df$Ensembl.ID
#[1] "ENSG00000113552" "ENSG00000113552" "ENSG00000249915" 
#[4] "ENSG00000249915" "ENSG00000095370"
#[6] "ENSG00000095370"
```

---

Or using `full_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
full_join(df1, df2, by = c("Entrez.ID","Gene.ID")) %>%
    group_by(Entrez.ID) %>%
    fill(Ensembl.ID, .direction = 'up') %>%
    fill(Ensembl.ID, .direction = 'down')
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Entrez.ID [3]
#  Entrez.ID Gene.ID Ensembl.ID     
#      <int> <chr>   <chr>          
#1     10007 GNPDA1  ENSG00000113552
#2     10007 GPI     ENSG00000113552
#3     10016 ALG2    ENSG00000249915
#4     10016 PDCD6   ENSG00000249915
#5     10044 SH2D3C  ENSG00000095370
#6     10044 CHAT    ENSG00000095370
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Entrez.ID = c(10007L, 10007L, 10016L, 10016L, 
10044L, 10044L), Gene.ID = c("GNPDA1", "GPI", "ALG2", "PDCD6", 
"SH2D3C", "CHAT"), Ensembl.ID = c(NA, "ENSG00000113552", NA, 
"ENSG00000249915", NA, "ENSG00000095370")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I tried for the full_join from dplyr solution, and it worked - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the df1’s Gene.ID and df2’s Gene.ID are unique (IDs in df1 are not IDs in df2), you can simply merge

```
df <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("Entrez.ID"),all.x=TRUE)
```

then use rbind()

```
df <- rbind(df, df2)
```

PS.I would recommend using data.table for data wrangling in the future. It is very intuitive and faster.